# VS2008 Entity Framework LazyLoading not available

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, ado.net

I am using ado entity framework in my asp.net mvc2 application. I want to set context's LazyLoading enabled=false. But this options is not available. its giving error for contextoptions.

How do I add this attributes to my .edmx file? do i need any upgrade as I am using vs2008?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4

Answer (score 1):

EFv1 (.NET 3.5) doesn't support transparent lazy loading so you don't need (and you can't) to change any settings. Lazy loading in EFv1 is always [triggered manually](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2008/08/20/entity-framework-and-lazy-loading.aspx) by calling `Load` method on navigation property.