# Entity Framework 4 Automatically Loading All References

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm working on a new project and got some experience with Entity Framework 3.5. Now that I'm building the model and writing the first methods I notice that Entity Framework 4 seems to load every reference to which a navigation property exists. In 3.5 I had to manually .Include() each entity that was referenced if I wanted to access them. It even loads nested references. I've got 3 tables that look something like this:

```
Container(PK: container_Id, Name),
Text(PK: text_Id, FK: container_Id, Name),
Binary(PK: binary_Id, FK: text_Id, Name)
```

and if I do `var containerList = Context.Container.ToList();` everything gets loaded, even down to the binary table.

Was this behavior changed or is there some options that I can use to disable this automatic loading of each and every reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading was enabled by default in EF 4. You can disable the lazy loading.

[Disable lazy loading by default in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4)