# How can I turn on and off lazy loading with EF 5?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

If I have the following objects:

```
public class Application 
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class TestAccount
{
    public int TestAccountId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

EF Mapping looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
    .HasMany(a => a.TestAccounts)
    .WithRequired(t => t.Application)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

In one part of my code I want to retrieve data for Application and have
it return TestAccount data.

In another part of my code I want to retrieve data for Application and
have it NOT return TestAccount data.

Is there a way I can make this happen with LINQ or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered here: [Disable lazy loading by default in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4).

Basically, in the constructor of your DbContext, just add this:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Also, if you want to know how to load it manually later, it should be a simple matter of using `Include()` like this:

`var query = context.Application.Include(x => x.TestAccounts).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another problem now. Will post and hope someone can help.