# Entity framework will execute additional query to the DB if i perform a .Select before the .tolist()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have the following Action method:-

```
public ActionResult RackServer(int id) {
            var servers = repository.AllFindRack_Servers(id).ToList();
            var IT360IDs = servers.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value).ToArray();

            return PartialView("~/Views/Server/_nonPagedServerTable.cshtml", servers);

        }
```

which calls the following repository method:-

```
public IQueryable<TMSServer> AllFindRack_Servers(int id)
        {



            return tms.TMSServers.Where(c => c.RackID == id)
            .Include(a => a.OperatingSystem)

            .Include(a3 => a3.TMSRack.DataCenter)
            .Include(a14 => a14.TMSRack.Technology)

            .Include(a6 => a6.TMSVirtualMachines)
            .Include(a7 => a7.TechnologyStatu)
            .Include(a8 => a8.TechnologyBackUpStatu)
            .Include(a9 => a9.TechnologyRole)
            .Include(a10 => a10.Technology.TechnologyIPs)
            .Include(a11 => a11.TMSServer1.Technology)
            .Include(a14=>a14.TMSServers1)
            .Include(a12 => a12.TMSSwitches)
            .Include(a13 => a13.TMSFirewalls);

        }
```

but i have noted that in case i chnage the .Tolist() position within my action method to be as:-

```
public ActionResult RackServer(int id) {
                var servers = repository.AllFindRack_Servers(id);
                var IT360IDs = servers.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value).Tolist().ToArray();

                return PartialView("~/Views/Server/_nonPagedServerTable.cshtml", servers);

            }
```

then two queries to the repository method will be done ? can anyone explain why having .Select & .Tolist() inside the same statement is causing two similar quires to be executed.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its doing lazy loading. turn lazy loading off and use "include" instead: ".include("tablename")"

include works as join in sql statements

turning lazyloading off: [Disable lazy loading by default in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score 0):

in your repository you are building your query where you are taking advantage of deferred execution

your first query fires on

```
 var IT360IDs = servers.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value).Tolist().ToArray();
```

this statement

second query on

```
 return PartialView("~/Views/Server/_nonPagedServerTable.cshtml", servers); 
 //as here you are accessing servers object
```

you have to replace **servers** with **IT360IDs**...