# Entity Framework related entities are loaded without explicit Load or Include call

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity model generated as below:

```
public partial class Entity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Entity()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        this.Fields = new HashSet<FieldEntity>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AssigneeID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }
    public int LastEditBy { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DeletedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual UserEntity Assignee { get; set; }
    public virtual UserEntity CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FieldEntity> Fields { get; set; }
    public virtual UserEntity LastEditByUser { get; set; }
}
```

When I use EF LinqToSql to fetch this entity, for some reason the list of `Comments` and `Fields` are populated even though I don't use `Include()` or `Load()` as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

This is a sample query I use:

```
var entities = ctx.MyEntities.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
```

I thought the default behavior was to lazily load related entities, so I'm trying to figure out if something is wrong with my query or my model.

For what it's worth, I did search my solution for `LazyLoadingEnabled` and it is supposed to be enabled:

```
//from MyDBModel.edmx
<EntityContainer Name="MyEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
...
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that they are loaded immediately and not when you access the collection/relationship?

Comment: @Igor if I put a breakpoint after running that query, I can inspect `entities` and it has the collections populated. I was under the impression that they would be null or otherwise empty without explicitly including the related entities. Is there a better way to verify if they are actually lazily loaded?

Comment: @Sami I tried that just now, and the debug inspection looks the same as with `Single`.

Comment: I just corrected a typo with the second call.. But now I began to doubt my self anyhow. Removing the comment..

Comment: @Igor you were right, they are being lazily loaded. It's just that when I inspect through the debugger, the related entities are then loaded rather than some sort of null or exception being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy Loading is enabled by default in EF. If you want to disable it, you can check the answer to this [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4) related with the same topic.

Also, you can confirm if your code is performing the Lazy Loading using the [SQL Server Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.120).aspx) tool. Check this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading/) for more information about how to do that.

Comment: I have SQLExpress, so I had to use [ExpressProfiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/), but it worked great out of the box.

Comment: @Michael Good to know that!