# Entity Framework Core getting Forein Key entities not possible with Npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql, .net-core

I have encountered in a strange behavior of Npgsql for Entity Framework Core:

My Models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Numbers = new List<TelephoneNumber>();
        Emails = new List<Email>();
    }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public List<TelephoneNumber> Numbers {get;set;}

    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public int EmailId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class TelephoneNumber
{
    public int TelephoneNumberId { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

And my DbContext:

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerContext> options) : base(options)
    {}
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Email> Emails {get;set;}
    public DbSet<TelephoneNumber> Numbers {get;set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerId);
        builder.Entity<Address>().HasKey(m => m.AddressId);
        builder.Entity<Email>().HasKey(m => m.EmailId);
        builder.Entity<TelephoneNumber>().HasKey(m => m.TelephoneNumberId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I have successfully connected to the postgresql database and the schema is created with "dotnet ef migrations add initPG" and "dotnet ef database update" without problems with right forein key constrains-etc..

Then i create a customer with:

```
var created = _context.Customers.Add(cust);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

With customer containing a address,email and telephone number.

My problem is when i want to get all customers from the DB with:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
```

I only get a Customers with empty Address, Email and TelephoneNumber properties!!

Do i have a logical misunderstanding here!? I would think the EF-Framework does the table joins automatically.
Or do i manually need to get this seperate elements from the customer by myself?

At several sources i see the **include** keyword to get the forein-key properties but my IDE shows that the DbContext has no **include** method at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want the `include` extension methods, type

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Or, if using EF 7, as per `rubiktubik`'s suggestion

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

at the top of your file

at that point, you should be able to do

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = _context.Customers
    .Include(c => c.Emails)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it necessary in ef to use include to get all foreign key properties?

Comment: @rubiktubik  I seem to remember there being a way to configure that behavior, but it will decrease performance.  If you must know, [A google search got me to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4)

Comment: it seems that lazy loading is not implemented in ef7 yet, so that the include method needs to be used

Comment: Yes, Include is (currently) necessary to get related data - read the docs: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying/related-data.html

Comment: I looked up the samples In Entity Framework Core and you need to use "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" to get Include to work! @SamIam if you correct this in your answer then i will accept your answer. :-)