# Disable LazyLoading in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I want to disable lazy loading in EF Core. Right now I have an infinite loop of loading relations. By running the below code, I get an Employee with all relations to the Employee, even if lazy loading is disabled.

```
public EmployeeProcess GetByEmployeeNr(int employeeNr)
    {
        if (_db.EmployeeProcess.Any(ep => ep.Employee.Id == employeeNr))
            return _db.EmployeeProcess.First(ep => ep.Employee.Id == employeeNr);
        return null;
    }
```

To turn of relations I have tried to write the following in the constructor of the context:

```
this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

I have also tried to do it in the repository by using:

```
db.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

On other posts I have read that Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false, is the way to go, but I have no Configuration in my Context.

The empty constructor looks like this:

```
public SalRegContext(DbContextOptions<SalRegContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

Does someone know how to get the configuration, or another solution to prevent the infinite loop of relations?

this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  Does not work..

Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; is not possible, as there is no configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[Disable lazy loading by default in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4)

try disabling lazy loading in the EntitiesContext

```
public MyEntitiesContext() : base("name=MyEntitiesContext", "MyEntitiesContext")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

see https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

[Disable lazy loading by default in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4)
(look for a configuration setting that is turning lazy loading on)

EDMX file should be edited by adding the `annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="false"`

Comment: I don't even use optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connectionString)..
I have:
'
public void EstablishDbContext(IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<SalRegContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionString), o =>
                {   
                    o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                });
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            });
        }
'

Comment: Also we don't use "proxy" anywhere in the code.. 
We are using EF Core 6.0..